# How to calculate spin from a set of translating images in python

Tags: python, opencv

I am wondering if this can be done:

I have a set of images that start out looking forward, as they move forward the camera spins horizontally in a 360 direction. 
So each image has a slightly different view as it spins around going forward. 
The question is; can I accurately calculate the spin that camera is moving?
A follow up question is can I calculate the direction the image is moving with the spin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea would be to use a few points that you would track across the transformation. And from those points you could find the angle of rotation between each frame.

You might want to have a look at this that explains the maths.
http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=671

If you don't need to stick to python, you could use matlab :
http://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/find-image-rotation-and-scale-using-automated-feature-matching.html?requestedDomain=uk.mathworks.com

Comment: Thanks Alby, I knew that I came across the answer many years ago but couldn't find it until now. Thank you for sharing the both links. The Matlab example is exactly what I needed along with the maths explanation. So what I am thinking now, if i remove the rotation of each image based of the features a I can then calculate the movement forward. Any thoughts?